# What are the valid subprotocols for HttpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync?

Tags: .net, websocket

And what is a subprotocol, for that matter?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenercontext.acceptwebsocketasync(v=vs.110).aspx

I found out you can just set this to `null`, and its accepted as a valid argument. But I still couldn't get my app working with that... so I wonder if it was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can just set this to `null`, and this is what you should do if your client is subprotocol oblivious, and doesn't need protocol negotation. I'll let someone else answer what is a subprotocol...

Comment: I have found that Chrome crashes if I try to send arrayByte frames without specify a subprotocol.